# Remember + used to?

Tags: used-to

The following:

> I went to stackoverflow for help

becomes:

> I remember go**ing** to stackoverflow for help

With that same logic, the following:

> I used to go to stackoverflow for help

would become:

> I remember us**ing** to go to stackoverflow for help

I know this is wrong, but I keep accidentally saying it lately..

**What is the correct way to combine "remember" and "used to"?**

Comment: I remember  when I used to .............but be careful, with negatives: I remember when I didn't use to.................Use stays in the infinitive because did is making the past tense.

Comment: If you can't use *I remember that I used to go...*, then you have painted yourself into a corner.

Comment: _Used to_ is a fixed phrase, an idiomatic marker that can't be changed, must be pronounced oddly (/yustu/, not /yuzdtu/), and needs to be followed by an infinitive. It is a tensed verb and must appear in a tensed clause (no infinitives, no participles) with a subject. So, as @BruceMurray suggests, a _wh_-clause (which is tensed), or a _that_-clause, also tensed, as YosefBaskin suggests.